# Math error using % in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, division

I am trying to use mod division to determine whether a year in a loop is a census or election year, and I have two issues:

**1**. I cannot get the wording in line with the year for ex:

It is like:

*`2000`*

*`this is an election year`*

*`this is a census year`*

*`2001`*

but I need it to say:

*`2000, this is an election year, this is a census year
2001 etc`*

**2** : My math is some sort of wrong but I am having trouble identifying why or where, the division needs to apply to a user entered year range, and it needs to divide each year by 10, or 4, and the years that have no remainder are election or census years, but it is not doing that properly, it is not dividing all of the years, just some. My code is this:

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Variables
    int startYr = 0;
    int endYr = 0;
    int yearDisp = 0;


    //Input Validation

    startYr = int.Parse(textBoxStartYr.Text);
    endYr = int.Parse(textBoxEndYr.Text);

    if (int.TryParse(textBoxStartYr.Text, out startYr))
    {
        //correct
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a four digit year");
        return;
    }
    if (int.TryParse(textBoxEndYr.Text, out endYr))
    {
        //correct
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a four digit year");
        return;
    }

    //Loop

    for (yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
    {
        listBoxDisp.Items.Add("Year:" + yearDisp.ToString());
        if (checkBoxCensus.Checked == true )
        {
            if ((yearDisp % 10) == 0)
            {
                listBoxDisp.Items.Add("This is a census year");
            }
            else { }
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing needed
        }
        if (checkBoxElection.Checked == true)
        {
            if ((yearDisp % 4) == 0)
            {
                listBoxDisp.Items.Add("This is an election year");
            }
            else { }                   
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing
        }               
    }       
}
```

Comment: You can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx): `listBoxDisp.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} This is an election year", yearDisp));`

Comment: @GrantWinney what does that mean? I try hard not to ask dumb questions, but this is the first class I've taken, so I'm not sure what to do with the information you supplied :)

Comment: @adelebeth I think he means you're implying `1988` is a census year in your post, when it is not divisible by 10.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that worked well!

Comment: @ryrich yes, I just used a random year number, I am not saying it is correct, I apologize.

Comment: @GrantWinney I picked a random number, I apologize, I was not saying 1999 was a census year. Will edit now. In my program, when I run it, lets say I enter 1988 as start year and 2020 as an end year, the program wont start the division until say, 1996 (or some other later year) it skips the first year in both census and election year division.

Comment: @adelebeth which years is it doing properly and which ones is it not doing properly?

Comment: you are executing int.parse before your input validation which means that if I enter an invalid input in the start year textbox, you will have an exception

Comment: @jsve the early years, it is different each time and does not matter if my date range is 1702 - 2030 or 2000 - 2010, it skips the first few years each time

Comment: @GrantWinney I can't solve the problem but I figured out why I thought it was skipping!!! OK when I select my year dates, it will run 3 times! the first time lists each year, the second time lists each year and whether or not it is an election year, and the third time lists each year and whether or not is is a census year! so in the date range 1988-2020 the year 1988 is in the list 3 times. How can I combine my code to get one list of each year, while still keeping the condition that the checkboxes must be checked?

Comment: Please edit your code to have only function that produces wrong results. Make sure to remove empty if/else cases. Make sure to not show either parsing part OR computation part.

Comment: no, the user checks whether they want to know if the year is an election or census year. IF the checkbox is checked, the program is supposed to display that information. If they are not checked, it will simply list every year between the start year user entered and the end year user entered.

Comment: @adelebeth are you using winforms or WPF? Just trying to see if my answer works for you.

Comment: Considering I have no idea what a WPF or winform is, I'd say no. I create everything in Visual Studio :)

Comment: @adelebeth :) if you hover over the listbox in your code, does it come from System.Windows.Forms or System.Windows.Controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your listbox issue.

```
for (yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
{
    int index = listBoxDisp.Items.Add("Year:" + yearDisp.ToString());
    if (checkBoxCensus.Checked == true)
    {
        if ((yearDisp % 10) == 0)
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items[index] += ",This is a census year";
        }
        else { }
    }
    else
    {
        //nothing needed
    }
    if (checkBoxElection.Checked == true)
    {
        if ((yearDisp % 4) == 0)
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items[index] += ",This is an election year";
        }
        else { }
    }
    else
    {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not downvote!! Idk who did but I appreciate your help and am trying to make it work properly in my program

Comment: @adelebeth haha, yea someone else did, probably because they think you are using WPF (listbox from Windows.Controls), in which case, my code above will not work.

Comment: @adelebeth is the whole problem with skipping numbers solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variables
    int startYr = 0;
    int endYr = 0;
    bool checkForCensus = checkBoxCensus.Checked;
    bool checkForElection = checkBoxElection.Checked;

    // Input Validation
    string errorMsg = "";
    if (!int.TryParse(textBoxStartYr.Text, out startYr))
        errorMsg += "Please enter a four digit year";

    if (!int.TryParse(textBoxEndYr.Text, out endYr))\
        errorMsg += String.Format("{0}Please enter a four digit year",
                                   errorMsg == "" ? "" : " ");

    if (errorMsg != "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg);
        return;
    }

    // Loop
    for (int yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
    {
        bool isCensusYear, isElectionYear;
        if (checkForCensus && (yearDisp % 10) == 0)
            isCensusYear = true;

        if (checkForElection && (yearDisp % 4) == 0)
            isElectionYear = true;

        listBoxDisp.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1}{2}{3}",
            yearDisp.ToString(),
            isCensusYear ? "this is a census year" : "",
            (isCensusYear && isElectionYear) ? "," : "",
            isElectionYear ? "this is an election year" : ""
        ));
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. The empty `if` and `else` statements are unnecessary. I have removed the to make them more concise.
2. On the topic of conditionals in `if` statements: the `!` means "not" or "the opposite of". Examples: `!false == true` and `!true == false`.
3. You do not need the initial `int.Parse()` statements because `TryParse()`'s second parameter is an out parameter (it outputs the parsed integer).
4. I created two variables which get the value of the check box. That way you don't have to check the value every time the loop is executed.
5. I used a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) and [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to determine what text to display.
6. Although you didn't mention it, I did change the input validation so that only one message box is displayed.

Comment: @adelebeth if you have any questions regarding this code, please let me know.

Comment: I am still unable to make "checkForCensus" and "checkForElection" work. I am trying a few things until I get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Variables
    int startYr = 0;
    int endYr = 0;
    int yearDisp = 0;


    //Input Validation

    if (!int.TryParse(textBoxStartYr.Text, out startYr))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a four digit year");
        return;
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(textBoxEndYr.Text, out endYr))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a four digit year");
        return;
    }

    //Loop

    for (yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
    {
        bool isElection = 0 == (yearDisp % 4);
        bool isCensus   = 0 == (yearDisp % 10);

        if (isCensus && checkBoxCensus.Checked && isElection && checkBoxElection.Checked)
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} This is a both a census year and an election year", yearDisp));
        }
        else if (isCensus && checkBoxCensus.Checked)
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} This is a census year", yearDisp));
        }
        else if (isElection && checkBoxElection.Checked)
        {
            listBoxDisp.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} This is an election year", yearDisp));
        }
        else {
            listBoxDisp.Items.Add(yearDisp.ToString());
        }
    }       
}
```

Here's a more concise version of the for loop:

```
    for (yearDisp = startYr; yearDisp <= endYr; yearDisp++)
    {
        bool isElection = (0 == (yearDisp % 4)) && checkBoxCensus.Checked;
        bool isCensus   = 0 == (yearDisp % 10) && checkBoxElection.Checked;

        string text = yearDisp.ToString();
        if (isCensus && isElection)
        {
            text += " This is a both a census year and an election year";
        }
        else if (isCensus)
        {
            text += " This is a census year", yearDisp;
        }
        else if (isElection)
        {
            text += " This is an election year";
        }
        listBoxDisp.Items.Add(text);
    }
```

Comment: that works except now it doesnt show each year in between . The years that ARENT census or election years also need to be displayed :/

Comment: well you can add that yourself, don't except him to do the whole work.

Comment: Note that this will only display "This is a census year" on years that are **both** census and election years.

Comment: @MutuYolbulan I do not expect ANYTHING other than helpful comments. My response was because I do not know how to make that happen, how to correct that issue. No one is required to help, but I appreciate those who do. I am learning.

Comment: @jsve Huh? There are never any years that are both census and election years.

Comment: The year 2000 should be both elec and census

Comment: Ah. You've changed things since your original post. At first you said 1999 (and all years ending in 9) were census years. Updated answer again using census years are divisible by 10.

Comment: yes, I have updated the original post a bit as well to keep with the updates :) Thank you so much for your input!